# nativescript-webview-interface event call back to app there is an issue - Migrating the pure Nativescript 5.x project to Nativescript 6

Tags: webview, nativescript, migrate

Using nativescript-webview-interface and event is registered to webview. Event is fired to app and it is working fine. But in nativescript 6 same code is not working.

```
var webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview-interface');
```

exports.onWebViewLoaded = function(args) {

```
var webview = args.object;

oWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webview, buildSrc());
```

// where build source returns the html string

```
webview.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args) => {
    //do something specific to app
});
oWebViewInterface.on("watchInc", (data) => {
      console.log("event watchInc - want to do something app specific"); 
      //not receiving this event
});

oWebViewInterface.on("watchEnd", (data) => {
    console.log("event watchEnd - want to do something app specific");
    //not receiving this event
}, 200); // Timeout needed as loading event is fired when nothing ready...
```

}

Comment: It looks like that this library is not maintained and could not be migrated to support NativeScript 6.x.x

Comment: Did you give a try for [nativescript-webview-ext](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks manoj. Moved to nativescript-webview-ext plugin and communication between webview and javascript is working fine.